# If $ G$ is a finite group of order $n=|G|,$ then $a^n = e $ for all $a$ in $G $?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I.N. Herstein's book has a theorem (Theorem 2.4.5 Abstract Algebra, Second Edition)

" If $ G$ is a finite group of order $n=|G|,$ then $a^n = e $ for all $a$ in $G $ ".

However, for $\mathbb Z_6, [2]^6=[64]=[4].$

Is there something missing in the theorem? Or have I misunderstood the theorem?

Comment: In $\Bbb{Z}_6$ the operation is the sum!

Comment: You can also consider the multiplicative group of nonzero elements relatively prime to 6 with the multiplication operation mod 6, but this group contains just 1 and 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an abelian group, like $\mathbb Z_6$, under *addition*, we have $$[2]^6 = 2 + 2+2+2+2+2 = 6(2) = 12$$

And $12 \equiv 0 \mod 6$, where $0$ is this groups identity $e$.

The notation $g^n$ simply is shorthand for "apply the group operation to group element $g$, $n$ times."